# Simple units question (School)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, units

A tank has 2000 litres of capacity (Ct). It fills at 5 l/s. It is filled with 800 l at time 0.

a) How many seconds will it need to fill half the tank.

So I did this:

X = time.

```
5 l   *  X     2000L
 ----       = -------   -  800L
  s           2


X =   200L
   ---------
     5  L
       ---
        s


X =   200
     -------
        5
    ---------
        s
```

Eventually, I get to `X = 40 / s`, but I guess it should be `X = 40s`.

However, I fail to see what I should do to get the seconds multiplying the 40.

PS: Shouldnt I give the X a unit at the beggining, or is it ok to be just X?

Comment: 1/(1/seconds)=seconds.

Comment: When you divide by $\frac {5L}{s}$, it is the same as multiplying by $\frac {s}{5L}$. Unfortunately, you forgot that you are dividing by $\frac{1}{s}$ or multiplying by $\frac{s}{1}$.

Comment: $\frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}} = \frac{a \cdot d}{b \cdot c}$

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you got confused when you had more than one dividing line. Try to maintain only one line and move inverted units above or below it instead of adding another line.

Another way to look at it is to maintain only one 'base' dividing line.  In your last step, you shifted the line (the longer line) from the upper to the lower line.  You can't do that and it makes for erroneous results.  40/sec is a VERY different answer from 40 sec.